# There always exists a sequence of consecutive composite integers of length $n$ for all $n$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Prove that there always exists a sequence of consecutive composite integers of length $n$, for all $n$.

Could you help solve this?

Comment: You mean arithmetic sequence?

Comment: If this is just about arithmetic sequences: *All* terms of the sequence $100n+10$ are composite (I deliberately avoided $0$)

Comment: I meant to say consecutive numbers

Comment: /APOSTOL/Ch4/Ex5

Answer (score 8):

Consider the sequence $(n+1)!+2,(n+1)!+3,\cdots ,(n+1)!+n+1$.
Each of these numbers is a composiite number since $(n+1)!+2$ is divisible by 2,$(n+1)!+3$ is divisible by 3 and so on.

Comment: what about n!+1? we are not getting a consecutive sequence.

Comment: You're right. I've made the necessary changes.